# Upgrading to SSMS with SQL Web Edition turned off Code Outlining : How do I get it back?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2 Web from Express with Advanced Services recently and code outlining went away. How do I get my collapsible code back?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the options in SSMS to see if it was just turned off during the upgrade?

Comment: Yes.I made sure all was the same as before the upgrade took place.

Comment: Try turning off the option, then turning it back on.

Comment: When 2008 first came out I remember there being issues with it not working depending on what engine you were connected to.  There was a popular tool as a work around that you can find here:  http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but Intellisense is not working either.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the latest service packs was the answer. Applied SP1 and cumulative updates from MS. Should have known, Windows, the service pack wonder.